# Qt5 .ui to .py conversion. '"C:\Python34\python" 'is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: python, conversion, user-interface, pyqt

I made a small GUI interface in QT Designer (file Login.ui), that I need to convert to a .py extension. I opened up console inside the folder and typed:

```
    C:\Users\Roman\Desktop\Python>pyuic5 -x Login.ui -o Login.py
```

Which gave me:

```
'"C:\Python34\python"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

It confused me because I do not have '"C:\Python34\python"' on my PC at all, so I tried another approach. This time I provided the full address to the pyuic5 by typing in the console:

```
C:\Users\Roman\Desktop\Python>C:/Python34/Lib/site-packages/PyQt5/pyuic5.bat 
-x Login.ui -o Login.py
```

Which gave me the same error. Any solutions/ideas?

Answer (score 0):

**Generating .py file from .ui**

> python -m PyQt5.uic.pyuic -x [FILENAME].ui -o [FILENAME].py